# Help Adding filter to Add Media button for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, admin, media, dashboard

I'm trying to add a filter to the add media button for a custom post type. I'm using add_filter('media_send_to_editor') and it work's fine, but I'm having difficulty finding a way to determine the post type of the admin page so that I can only perform the filter on that specific post type. Any ideas on how I can get the post post type?

I'm trying to filter the output of the image and caption, but I only want to do it on a specific post type. I would need the other post types to function as normally when adding images. I need the the image to be wrapped in a shortcode and the caption to be included in a parameter for that shortcode. I have it working. I just need a way to make it conditional for post types.

Comment: what do you want to filter ? edit your question to add more details and a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to test the post type where the image is included, try that :

```
add_filter("media_send_to_editor", function ($html, $attachment_id, $attachment) {


    $image = get_post($attachment_id);
    $post = get_post($image->post_parent);

    if ("CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_CODE" === $post->post_type) {


    }


    return $html;

}, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

**PS : this doesn't answer the question but can help readers**

you can conditionaly remove the button withe the filter `wp_editor_settings`

```
add_filter("wp_editor_settings", function ($settings, $editor_id) {

    $current_screen = get_current_screen();

    if ("CUSTOM_POST_TYPE" === $current_screen->post_type) {
        $settings["media_buttons"] = FALSE;
    }


    return $settings;

}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually want to continue to include the upload media button. I only want to filter it for the specific post type.